# Bind non-property to datagrid column DataField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

Let's say I have a DataGrid that looks something like:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="SomeDataGrid" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="A Header" SortExpression="Sort" DataField="Data"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

In this Grid, I set the datasource to some collection that contains a public property called "Data" and do a `databind()`. Every works as expected.

Now let's say I want to set the DataField attribute of the column to a public member, or a property, or some other thing I've computed. What is the easiest way to go about this without creating intermediate objects or adding public properties to the objects in the collection?

So what I want to do is something like:

```
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="A Header" SortExpression="Sort" DataField="someMethod()"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn.aspx)

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Test">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# SomeMethod() %>'></asp:Label>  
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```